# Binding to another viewmodel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I am trying to bind a visibility property to a function I made in a viewmodel (`MainViewModel`), but I am getting this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Main' property not found on 'Locator' 'System.String' (HashCode=-191326816). BindingExpression: Path='Main.TilesHomeViewVisible' DataItem='Locator' (HashCode=-191326816); target element is 'myApp.Views.TilesHomeView' (Name='myTilesHomeView'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'System.Windows.Visibility')..

From what I understand from the error, it is looking for the `TilesHomeViewVisible` function in the `TilesHomeViewModel`, while it is actually in the `MainViewModel`. In the binding expression, how do I target the `MainViewModel` then?

EDIT: I have a 'ViewModelLocator' integrated .

Here is my ViewModelLocator:

```
    ...
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TilesHomeViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public TilesHomeViewModel TilesVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TilesHomeViewModel>();
        }
    }
...
```

My App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application x:Class="myApp.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:app="clr-namespace:myApp" mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:myApp.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myApp.ViewModels">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <app:ColorWrapper x:Key="ColorWrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="ResourceDictionary1" Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated" />
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

In my MainPage.xaml and where the linking to the locator was made , I have:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    ...
>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="Main" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    ...
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        ...
        <local:TilesHomeView x:Name="myTilesHomeView" Visibility="{Binding Main.TilesHomeViewVisible,Source=Locator}" />
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(); 
    }
    Visibility _tilesHomeViewVisible = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    public Visibility TilesHomeViewVisible
    {
        get { return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; }
        set { _tilesHomeViewVisible = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TilesHomeViewVisible"); }
    }

    public void TilesHomeViewClose()
    {
        TilesHomeViewVisible = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadData()
    {...}
}
```

TilesHomeView.xaml has it data context defined as so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myApp.Views.TilesHomeView"
....
DataContext="{Binding TilesVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
>

    <Grid x:Name="HomeGrid">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

HomeViewModel.cs is has no function and is presented as such

```
namespace myApp
{
    public class TilesHomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public TilesHomeViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is as detailed as possible. I really hope to find a solution to this error, it's been bugging me for days now.

Thanks

Comment: post the .xaml of the page, what is needed is the context of binding, not the binding definition.

Comment: please post the code behind

Comment: I have updated my post with more code to detail the situation. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are probably you are setting TilesHomeViewModel as the DataContext on the root of your TilesHomeView usercontrol (so that mean that the DataContext of TilesHomeView element is also TilesHomeView ). 
Here is two possible solution to this problem:

When setting the the visibility explicitely set the source :

```
<local:TilesHomeView x:Name="myTilesHomeView" Visibility="{Binding Main.TilesHomeViewVisible,Source={StaticResource Locator} }" />
```

(Update with the appropriate value on your locator)

-A second solution is to move where you set the DataContext to TilesHomeViewModel  in your UserControl: set the DataContext the LayoutRoot grid of the User control instead of the root.

Comment: Hi, I used the code you provided me, but it still cannot find the function. See my updated code for the error message, and a better view of some my app's classes and pages

Comment: @JNate updated my answer, it  is {StaticResource Locator} you need to use instead of just Locator (otherwise it bind the source to the string Locator instead of the Locator resource

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot!!
I managed to have to have the TileshomeView appear and disappear, however I noticed that when the tiles reappear, it won't show the data inside the tiles anymore. My hubtiles were created using the windows phone toolkit. What do you think I could be doing wrong? Do you think I should call a function to reload the data everytime the tiles are called back?

Comment: Normally you should not need to call any "reload" method, are you binding the data inside the tile? If not how are you filling in the data?