# RaisePropertyChanged not firing when function called from another viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am having an issue updating the interface of my windows phone 7 app I am working on.

I have a `MainPage.xaml` and its `MainViewModel.cs` which handle how a child view usercontrol `ChildView1.xaml` appears in the MainPage. ChildView1 also has its ViewModel which is `Child1ViewModel.cs`. Basically a `myToggleButton` gets fired from the MainPage which will trigger a `DataStateBehavior` to go into a show or hide state to respectively show or hide the `ChildView1.xaml`. That DataStateBehavior is binded to the boolean `CanShowView` while the `myToggleButton` is binded to an `Icommand` named `ButtonChecked` which has a relay function `SwitchVisibility` that will reverse the `CanShowView` boolean to show or hide the view. All works well thanks to the `RaisePropertyChanged` of the MVVM light I used.

However, the `ChildView1.xaml` has a `myCloseButton` which is supposed to call the `SwitchVisibility` function from MainViewModel which would in turn revert the `CanShowView` and the `RaisePropertyChanged` in `CanShowView` should fire to have `ChildView1` close, but the issue is that the view stays visible and never closes for some reason! I noticed through the debugger that the `RaisePropertyChanged` in `CanShowView` seems to not fire. I suppose that's where the problem lies. What are my doing wrong? How can I force it to fire? I used multiple `RaisePropertyChanged` but none seem to fire even though the degugger shows that the value in my function did change.

Here is my code.
MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="Main" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    ...
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        ...
        <ToggleButton x:Name="myToggleButton" Command="{Binding Main.ButtonChecked, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
        <local:ChildView1 x:Name="myChildView1" Grid.Row="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ec:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding Main.CanShowView, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Value="True" TrueState="showChildView1" FalseState="hideChildView1"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ChildView1.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </local:ChildView1.RenderTransform>
        </local:ChildView1>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainViewModel.cs :

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand ButtonChecked { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ButtonChecked = new RelayCommand(() => SwitchVisibility()); 
    }

    public void SwitchVisibility()
    {
        CanShowView = !CanShowView;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CanShowView");
    }

    bool _canShowView = true;
    public bool CanShowView
    {
        get { return _canShowView; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _canShowView)
            {
                _canShowView = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CanShowView");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ChildView1.xaml :

```
<UserControl x:Class="myApp.Views.ChildView1"
....
DataContext="{Binding Child1VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
>

    <Grid x:Name="HomeGrid">
        <Button x:Name=myCloseButton Command="{Binding Child1VM.CloseChildViewCmd, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Child1ViewModel.cs :

```
namespace myApp
{
    public class Child1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand CloseChildViewCmd { get; private set; }
        public Child1ViewModel()
        {
            CloseChildViewCmd = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteCloseChildViewCmd());
        }

        public void ExecuteCloseChildViewCmd()
        {
            MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
            MainViewModel mainVM = new MainViewModel();
            mainPage.DataContext = mainVM;
            mainVM.SwitchVisibility();

        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am only a beginner programmer so the way I am tackling the issue or the program itself might be questionable, hence I am open to any suggestions, and code samples are very welcome. I have been stuck with this issue for many days now after doing a lot of research and experimenting many things that never seemed to work. I took the time to write the issue in detail and am really hopeful that I could find a solution here. Let me know if ever there are more details you need to know.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I read creating a new instance of the views is not a solution. How else can I access fire the `MainView`'s functions and have properties raised?

EDIT: As suggested by OmegaMan, I am using static definitions to call my functions.
So the updated `MainViewModel.cs`:
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand ButtonChecked { get; private set; }
        private static MainViewModel Primary { get; set; }

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ButtonChecked = new RelayCommand(() => SwitchVisibility()); 
        Primary = this;
    }

    public void SwitchVisibility()
    {
        CanShowView = !CanShowView;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CanShowView");
    }

    public static void SwitchViewStatic()
    {
        Primary.SwitchVisibility();
    }

    bool _canShowView = true;
    public bool CanShowView
    {
        get { return _canShowView; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _canShowView)
            {
                _canShowView = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CanShowView");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The updated `Child1ViewModel.cs`:
    namespace myApp
    {
        public class Child1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            public ICommand CloseChildViewCmd { get; private set; }
            public Child1ViewModel()
            {
                CloseChildViewCmd = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteCloseChildViewCmd());
            }

```
        public void ExecuteCloseChildViewCmd()
        {
            MainViewModel.SwitchViewStatic();

        }
    }
}
```

The desired function in MainViewModel gets called by myCloseButton from the child view, but `CanShowView` still won't get raised to permit the DataStateBehavior listening to it, to update the UI... So I am still at an impass.

Comment: Which mvvm framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having the children hold a reference to the main view model, but why is the control creating a new MainViewModel? Pass in the MainViewModel and call SwitchVisibility off it...or make a static method on the MainVM which will access the actuall VM and call instance SwitchVisiblity.

--- Update to show the static method access from the MainVM

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private static MainViewModel Primary { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Primary = this;
    }

    public static void SwitchViewStatic()
    {
        Primary.SwitchVisibility();
    }

    public void SwitchVisibility()
    {
    ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be wrong indeed. Like I said to McGarnagle, I thought I read somewhere that it would call the most recent state of the app. In my previous attempts, I did not instantiate the view and still was not able to have property raised.

For the static method, you mean I could just create for instance `public static void LaunchSwitcher(){ SwitchVisibility();}` and have that method called from the child view? If so, how would I call that method from that child viewmodel without instantiating the main view, or it wouldn't matter? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JNate For the static method idea, have the constructor of the VM fill in itself to a static variable (the this instance). Then have the static method use that static variable and call the SwitchVisibility.

Comment: I looked into where to create the static variable in order to store MainViewModel but no luck. Did you mean something like `public static var myVar = this` to define in the MainViewModel? I tried to define it but I get error messages on the var and this. At which point was I supposed to define it. Is this what you meant by static variable that would call the MainViewModel?
If I am able to create myVar, I believe this is what it is suppose to do:
`public static void LaunchSwitcher(){ myVar.SwitchVisibility();}`
Correct?

Comment: It would be really great if you could update my MainViewModel code so I can see better where those are to be defined. Or at least your answer.

Comment: @JNate Here is the example...Simply call MainViewModel.SwitchViewStatic() anywhere in the code to update.

Comment: I integrated it and it did call the function!! However it still was not able to fire the `RaisePropertyChanged("CanShowView")` located inside that `CanShowView` function eventhough its value did change according to the debugger. Is it possible that `DataStateBehavior` is not listening to its binding when the binded(`CanShowView`) is called indirectly from another viewmodel? Is there maybe a way to make it listen the binding in a persistent way?

Comment: My mistake, it's the `DataStateBehavior` that is bound to 'CanShowView' . I gave it the wrong name in my code sample of the MainPage view but I corrected it. It does have the right binding name in my actual code since when myToggleButton is pressed and gets `CanShowView` raised, it gets the `DataStateBehavior` to change the UI. However, as mentioned earlier, it does not want to proceed the same way when it's the `myCloseButton` that tries to raise the `CanShowView`.

Comment: @JNate Something is up with the control binding, not the notify property. I am guessing that the ChildView1 is either not actually bound to the VM or that it is bound to a different instance of the VM.

Comment: That is a possibility. I noticed I always thought the way I calling my bind to be a bit unusual way.
Could you take a look at my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206902/binding-to-another-viewmodel

What I call TilesHomeView is actually what I renamed here `ChildView1` for simplicity. Do you think I am missing something maybe in the binding to the `ViewModel` `Locator`, or something wrong with the way I assign the `datacontext`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39222/discussion-between-omegaman-and-jnate)

Comment: @JNate Can't respond in chat due to company policy...so see last comment with link and respond here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips. I will be going with integrating my own view model.

I tested the codes from your blog post on a new project since I was getting some errors. I managed a to fix a few things that might interest some bloggers going through that post and having issues. Windows Phone 7 is based on the .net 4 Framework and 'CallerMemberName' is based on the 4.5 Framework so I installed through Nuget the Microsft.BCL components to fix it. Also as for the WPF test app, I had to include 'using System.Windows' since 'Window' could not be recognized when defining 'MainWindow' partial class.

Comment: @JNate I feel for you on WP7...its a shame you are not on WP8. It drove me nuts on my last WP8 project when I wanted to do something in *wpf* xaml that WP8 Xaml didn't allow. Sounds like you are getting it though. GL

Comment: For my windows phone app, the only issues I have remaining are:
when setting the 'DataContext' in the codebehind as so: 'DataContext = ViewModel = new MainViewModel()', I get the error with 'ViewModel' underlined and stating that 'myAppName.ViewModel' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'variable'. The other issue appears when I am trying to reload the designer and after I removed 'x:Type' to write: 'd:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModels/MainViewModel}", the error message states that 'ViewModel/MainViewModel' was not found. Same thing with shortening it to just 'MainViewModel'.

Comment: I don't know if the two issues are related though.
I Should add that I did add the namespace into the '.xaml' as 'xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:myApp.ViewModels"'.
 As for the fact I chose WP7, I wanted to have my app initially available for WP7 before releasing it for WP8

Comment: @JNate IMHO upgrade to WP8 because everyone who has had a WP7 has upgraded; because why not if the phone is $50. As to the DC = VM = new ViewModel() ... does the VM live in a different namespace?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're sending a message to a new MainPage object and view model, not the existing one.

What you need is either a delegate or an event. The trick is connecting the Main Page to the Child Page.

If you need to keep them separate, you need an object to send the event along. This called an Event Aggregator, or messenger. You main viewmodel would need to subscribe to a CloseChild event that the child view model would send when the command is executed. The event aggregator transfers the message.

Note: Most MVVM frameworks implement a messenger of some kind that your view models can use to send and receive messages / events.

If you want to implement one yourself, take a look [here](http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/) for a way to create one.